# Angularjs and controlling menus

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and web development in general. I can't get my head around on how to build code for my menu system in a more elegant way. I should somehow find a way to build a function to control the state of menus so that when e.g. menu 2 is opened, menu 1 (or any other menu for that matter) closes simultaneously. I have a fiddle to show what I'm after: https://jsfiddle.net/cm70947/5e3d8j33/

When you look at the controller part of the code and keep clicking, you get the idea. The functionality is ok, but the code in the controller is terrible to maintain. Any help is much appreciated!

Html:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="menuController">
        <div id="menuButton" ng-click="openMenu()">MENU - CLICK HERE</div>
        <div class="mainMenu"  ng-class="{'mainMenu_active' : activated}">
            <ul>
                <li ng-click="openFirstMenu()">menu_first</li>
                <li ng-click="openSecondMenu()">menu_second</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div class="menuFirst" ng-class="{'menuFirst_active' : firstMenuActivated}">THIS IS FIRST MENU</div>
        <div class="menuSecond" ng-class="{'menuSecond_active' : secondMenuActivated}">THIS IS SECOND MENU</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('menuController', function($scope){
            $scope.activated = false;
            $scope.openMenu = function() {
                $scope.activated = !$scope.activated;
                $scope.secondMenuActivated = false;
                $scope.firstMenuActivated = false;
            };

            $scope.firstMenuActivated = false;
            $scope.openFirstMenu = function() {
                $scope.firstMenuActivated = !$scope.firstMenuActivated;
                $scope.secondMenuActivated = false;
            };

            $scope.secondMenuActivated = false;
            $scope.openSecondMenu = function() {
                $scope.secondMenuActivated = !$scope.secondMenuActivated;
                $scope.firstMenuActivated = false;
            };

        });
```

Comment: are you using ngRoute or UIRouter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want additional libaries, I created a fiddle for you in plain angular which might be a solution that is a bit more scalable: https://jsfiddle.net/ypneg5z5/2/

I tried to leverage ng-repeat and then use the index to activate the correct submenu.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="menuController">
        <div id="menuButton" ng-click="openMenu()">MENU - CLICK HERE</div>
        <div class="mainMenu"  ng-class="{'mainMenu_active' : activated}">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-click="select($index)">{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div class="menu menu0" ng-class="{'menu_active': itemIndex===0}">THIS IS FIRST MENU</div>
        <div class="menu menu1" ng-class="{'menu_active': itemIndex===1}"> THIS IS SECOND MENU</div>
        <div class="menu menu2" ng-class="{'menu_active': itemIndex===2}"> THIS IS THIRD MENU</div>
        <div class="menu menu3" ng-class="{'menu_active': itemIndex===3}"> THIS IS FOURTH MENU</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I dried up your CSS. "menu" contains all the styling shared by all submenus (I had to set them to position absolute to make it work for more than 2 menus.) "menu0", etc. contains the individual styling. You can of course call them whatever you want.

Also think about whether you can generate the submenus the same way I did it for the menu items (ng-repeat on some data in your controller). That way you would only have to change the data arrays and the styling if you want to make changes later.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Actually I tried this approach as I had already found some examples of this but I couldn't implement them in my context. I will take a closer look at this!

Comment: If you feel this helped you please mark as accepted. That way I get some funny points for time I spent to sort this out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use AngularUI directive btn-radio for the menu items and then switch ng-class based on value of the btn-radio like this

```
<li ng-model="model" btn-radio="'menuFirst_active'">menu1</li>
<li ng-model="model" btn-radio="'menuSecond_active'">menu2</li>
```

Then in the menu div:

```
<div class="menu" ng-class="model">BLAHBLAH</div>
```

See more information here 
[here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) And then search for 'btn-radio'

Comment: HI, thank you for the idea. I will also take a look at this approach as well!